# What is the correct way to register a custom converter for Spring 4 @RequestParam or @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to figure out what is the "best" or recommended way for customer converters for RequestParams and PathVariables in Spring 4? We have registered our Jackson JSON converters, but they don't work for these parameters, and from reading online I've found about a dozen different answers on what should be done.

I originally thought LocalDateTime would work without a custom converter with the standard ISO format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss but when I pass that up (2014-12-01T01:01:01) it just throws an exception, and I tried different formats to see if those would work, but so far none of the formats I've tried have worked, so I was going to try a custom converter, but I can't seem to find what the correct way to do that is either.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
@RestController
public class TestController{
    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test(@RequestParam("stuff") LocalDateTime source) {
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the sample url I tried `http://localhost:8081/data/foo/test?start=1986-04-08T12:30:00`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper formatting for your case would be

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public void test(@RequestParam("stuff")  @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime source) {
    int i = 0;
}
```

just make sure one thing, in the value you pass and state in your question `2014-12-01T:01:01:01` you have a typo, it should be `2014-12-01T01:01:01` so no semi-colon betweeen `T` and `01`

Comment: Sorry that was a mistype in the question. I Was actually sending the correct string. http://localhost:8081/data/foo/test?start=1986-04-08T12:30:00

Comment: oki, reckoned so, but setting iso=ISO.DATE_TIME @DateTimeFormat works for you now?

Comment: It did thanks, I ended up making requests to the wrong url in part of my testing which is partly why I didn't think the DateTimeFormat thing worked. Although I'm surprised that it's needed since the ISO is supposed to be the default for LocalDateTime.parse().

Answer (score 0):

try checking out the @DateTimeFormat Parameter Annotation which was introduced with [Spring 3 Type Conversions and Validations](http://spring.io/blog/2009/11/17/spring-3-type-conversion-and-validation/):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/appointments/{day}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAppointmentsForDay(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date day) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't appear to work for LocalDateTime, it appears to work for dates though